# java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.awaitTermination() doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I have a problem. The code that follows pool.awaitTermination() is not executed.

```
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);

        for (HierarchyItem rootItem : rootObjectItems) {
            pool.submit(() -> {
                final Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
                currentThread.setName("Processing " + rootItem.getName());
                try {
                    addressObjectProcessor.handle(rootItem);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }

        pool.shutdown();
        try {
            boolean poolTermination = pool.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.HOURS);
            System.out.println(poolTermination);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /// code after pool.awaitTermination. It's not executed
         . . . .
```

I see in my logs, that all tasks are absolutely completed, but the code after `pool.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.HOURS);` doesnt execute. This problem appears when `rootObjectItems` size is 90. When the `rootObjectItems` size is 15, everything works fine, but when I increase `rootObjectItems`, it looks like the main thread sleeps or stops running this method, and nothing happens even after timeout. Every task processing takes from 5 to 60 minutes.

`pool.awaitTermination` result is never printed to logs, and the InterruptedException is never thrown.

I am new in concurrent, please, help me solve this problem. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you really so sure the tasks completed? Given the problem occurs when you have larger numbers of longer tasks, I suspect the submitted tasks have not completed.  Example: 60 tasks at one hour each with a thread pool of 6 will take at least 10 hours, using all of your 5 hour wait.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I mean "increase". I am absolutely sure that all the tasks are completed.  I determine this by the logs inside the tasks.  All tasks are completed in approximately 3 hours and 50 minutes.

Comment: Check the threads if they are really all finished. Use a tool like VisualVM or on command line `jstack` to see the threads stack traces.

Comment: Anyway, if the tasks were interrupted by timeout, the code after awaitTermination would have been executed. Or am I still wrong?

Comment: Also please clarify why the code after `pool.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.HOURS)` doesn’t execute: is it because `awaitTermination` throws or is it never returning? If you’re not sure, a thread dump will tell you that, too. Have you tested waiting the entire five hours?

Comment: Tim Moore, thank you for your answer. awaitTermination never retuns anything. I have tested waiting the entire 5 hours, but nothing happened. There was no any exception or awaitTermination result.

Answer (score 0):

## Capture result of `awaitTermination`

I suggest you do some debugging by recreating the scenario, as simply as possible. Add pieces to get closer to your current scenario.

Most importantly,  track what is happening to your `awaitTermination`. Your code ignores its return value, a `boolean`. To quote [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)):

> Returns: `true` if this executor terminated and `false` if the timeout elapsed before termination

Here is some simplified code to begin with.

By the way, I recommend *not* using the term *pool* in regards to your executor service. An executor service may or may not involve a backing pool of threads. The point of the service is to let us ignore details of managing threads and thread pools.

```java
System.out.println ( "Demo begins. " + Instant.now ( ) );
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool ( 6 );

List < Integer > numbers = IntStream.rangeClosed ( 1 , 100 ).boxed ( ).toList ( );
for ( Integer number : numbers )
{
    executorService.submit ( ( ) ->
    {
        Thread.currentThread ( ).setName ( "Processing " + number );
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofMinutes ( 60 ) );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            System.out.println ( "Sleep interrupted on thread: " + Thread.currentThread ( ).getName ( ) );
            return;
        }
        System.out.println ( "Finished the run for # " + number + " on thread: " + Thread.currentThread ( ).getName ( ) );
    } );
}

executorService.shutdown ( );
try
{
    System.out.println ( "Awaiting termination. " + Instant.now ( ) );
    boolean awaitTerminatedBeforeTimeLimit = executorService.awaitTermination ( 5 , TimeUnit.MINUTES );
    System.out.println ( "awaitTerminatedBeforeTimeLimit = " + awaitTerminatedBeforeTimeLimit );
}
catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace ( ); }
System.out.println ( "Demo done. " + Instant.now ( ) );
```

When run:

```
Demo begins. 2023-05-30T23:20:47.255904Z
Awaiting termination. 2023-05-30T23:20:47.263300Z
awaitTerminatedBeforeTimeLimit = false
Demo done. 2023-05-30T23:25:47.289905Z
```

Notice that `awaitTerminatedBeforeTimeLimit` is `false`. This means getting all our tasks done took more time than we allowed in our specified time limit passed to `awaitTermination`.

### Improperly neglected shutdown of executor service

Also, very importantly, notice that the backing **thread pool of our executor service is still running** even though our app supposedly ended.

- You can tell this in deployment because a Java process will still be running, unexpectedly.
- Within in an IDE such as IntelliJ, you will see that the *Run* status of the app execution has not ceased. In IntelliJ that appears as red *Stop* button with the rounded square icon will still be active, still red, meaning the app has not entirely ended yet.

To avoid this zombie ‍♂️ thread pool, completely shut down your executor service.

To properly shutdown your executor service, see the boilerplate code given to you in the Javadoc of the [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) interface. Look for the method named `shutdownAndAwaitTermination`. Here is my slightly modified version of that code.

```java
private void shutdownAndAwaitTermination ( final ExecutorService executorService , final Duration waitForTermination )
{
    executorService.shutdown ( ); // Disallow any more task submissions to this executor service.
    try
    {
        // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate.
        if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination ( waitForTermination.toMillis ( ) , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS ) )
        {
            executorService.shutdownNow ( ); // Cancel currently executing tasks
            // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled.
            if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination ( 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) )
                System.err.println ( "Executor service did not terminate. " + Instant.now ( ) );
        }
    }
    catch ( InterruptedException ex )
    {
        // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
        executorService.shutdownNow ( );
        // Preserve interrupt status
        Thread.currentThread ( ).interrupt ( );
    }
}
```

Let's revise our code to call that method for graceful shutdown of the executor service.

```java
System.out.println ( "Demo begins. " + Instant.now ( ) );
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool ( 6 );

List < Integer > numbers = IntStream.rangeClosed ( 1 , 100 ).boxed ( ).toList ( );
for ( Integer number : numbers )
{
    executorService.submit ( ( ) ->
    {
        Thread.currentThread ( ).setName ( "Processing " + number );
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofMinutes ( 60 ) );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            System.out.println ( "Sleep interrupted on thread: " + Thread.currentThread ( ).getName ( ) );
            return;
        }
        System.out.println ( "Finished the run for # " + number + " on thread: " + Thread.currentThread ( ).getName ( ) );
    } );
}

this.shutdownAndAwaitTermination ( executorService , Duration.ofMinutes ( 5 ) );
System.out.println ( "Demo done. " + Instant.now ( ) );
```

When run:

```
Demo begins. 2023-05-31T05:46:17.163745Z
Sleep interrupted on thread: Processing 3
Sleep interrupted on thread: Processing 1
Sleep interrupted on thread: Processing 4
Sleep interrupted on thread: Processing 5
Sleep interrupted on thread: Processing 6
Sleep interrupted on thread: Processing 2
Demo done. 2023-05-31T05:51:17.182036Z
```

We have the same situation, where our running tasks need more time than we allow. But now, notice (a) our executing tasks were interrupted successfully, and (b) the app has truly ended. Be sure to write your own tasks so that they properly look for the interrupt flag.

---

Tip: If you are sure your tasks will finish within a day, in modern Java you can use try-with-resources syntax to take advantage of `ExecutorService` now being `AutoCloseable`.

Comment: Basil, thank you so much for your answer! I will definitely take your advice to properly shutdown your executor service. I tracked, what had happened to my awaitTermination. It turned out, that awaitTermination result is never got. I changed my code to print it to logs, but it is never printed to logs. And the InterruptedException is never thrown. It seems to me, that the main thread dies before all the tasks complete. Do you know why this might happen?